# SharePoint/Exchange Calendar Overlay - Different Domains

Tags: 2013, calendar, exchange

We're using SharePoint 2013 internally and use a third-party provider for Exchange. This presents a problem when using Exchange calendar overlays in SharePoint as they're not on the same domain.

Is it possible to supply separate (401 challenge) credentials for the Exchange OWA and EWS URLs? Or does anyone else have a workaround for this type of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I have just posted [an alternative way of solving your issue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/178494/7288) that addresses a similar [SharePoint Stackexchange question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/169174/is-there-an-oob-way-to-display-an-outlook-group-calendar-as-a-calendar-overlay-i).  If your users use the Outlook client, this solution can work for you in your different domain situation if the permissions and authentication are set up correctly by your admins.

My suggested solution uses SharePoint calendar subscriptions within the Outlook client to a single SharePoint calendar that is writable to all team members.  We have been using this model with much success at work over the last 5 years.  We also have SharePoint hosted on prem (local domain) and Exchange hosted at an external domain.